# How to handle Cross domain HTML form POST submission using SpringBoot

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, web-services

I am new to Spring boot and also web development.I am writing an application where I need to handle the simple HTML form submission from the remote server.

HTML form contains Username, Password and submit button. I am providing the URL of my server which has controller to handle the request in **action**  in form tag .

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/login")  
public String confirmation(HttpServletRequest request,Credentials cred)   {
  cred.setPassword(request.getParameter("username"));
  cred.setUsername(request.getParameter("password"));
  //doing dome Business Logic here
  return "redirect";
}
```

I even tried adding `consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE}` in `RequestMapping` but it didn't help.

I used POSTMAN Client to test the URL.I used `Content-Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and Body as `form-data`.
I am getting the below error

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

My application handles SOAP request as well using `MessageDispatcherServlet` and I am using `DispatcherServlet` to handle REST calls. 
Please guide me whether I need to use specific `content-type` to handle HTML form data or do I need to specify anything in form submission tag in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are posting a form the browser send a HTTP request with the head `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

A SOAP service expect the `Content-Type` to be `application/soap+xml` that why you get the stack trace.

If you want to do that you should post you form to another endpoint that will transform the post to a SOAP request.

With postman set the correct content-type

Answer (score 0):

i created simple boot service. testing from postman. it is returing html form response..

```
Below is Response:
------------------------
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>
        <form name='f' action='/login' method='POST'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='username' value=''>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='password' name='password'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="f316e1ee-8cdb-4125-ac84-3629309d1a75" />
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```